# how to get my dynamic IP xcode

Tags: android, ip, ip-address

When you have a mobile connection, you often have 2 IP Addresses, an external IP which can be consulted in http://www.whatsmyip.org/

IP result: 190.106.XX.XX

and when I connect my PC to a BAM I get another IP as shown in

[image]

IP result: 10.69.XX.XX

the ipAddress I need to get is the one from the Window for using it (10.69.XX.XX)

I checked an android app and shown this result as RMNET0

and told me in java he used **request.getRemoteHost().** for obtaining this data

Any information I will appreciate

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this with success I hope it helps you

```
+(NSString *)getIpLocally:(NSString *)networkInterface ipVersion:(int)ipVersion
{
    if(ipVersion != 4 && ipVersion != 6)
    {
        NSLog(@"getIpLocally unknown version of IP: %i",ipVersion);
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *networkInterfaceRef;

    if ([networkInterface isEqualToString:@"ios_cellular"])
    {
        networkInterfaceRef = @"pdp_ip0";
    }
    else if([networkInterface isEqualToString:@"ios_wifi"])
    {
        networkInterfaceRef = @"en0"; //en1 on simulator if mac on wifi
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"getIpLocally unknown interface: %@",networkInterface);
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *address = nil;
    struct ifaddrs *addrs = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *cursor = NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in *s4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *s6;
    char buf[64];
    int success = 0;

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&addrs);
    if (success == 0)
    {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        cursor = addrs;
        while(cursor != NULL)
        {
            if((ipVersion == 4 && cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) ||
               (ipVersion == 6 &&  cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6))
            {
                NSLog(@"Network Interface: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cursor->ifa_name]);

                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cursor->ifa_name] isEqualToString:networkInterfaceRef])
                {
                    if(ipVersion == 4)
                    {
                        s4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)cursor->ifa_addr;

                        if (inet_ntop(cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family, (void *)&(s4->sin_addr), buf, sizeof(buf)) == NULL)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"%s: inet_ntop failed for v4!\n",cursor->ifa_name);
                        }
                        else{
                            address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
                        }
                    }
                    if (ipVersion == 6)
                    {
                        s6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)(cursor->ifa_addr);

                        if (inet_ntop(cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family, (void *)&(s6->sin6_addr), buf, sizeof(buf)) == NULL)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"%s: inet_ntop failed for v6!\n",cursor->ifa_name);
                        }
                        else{
                            address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(addrs);
    return address;
}
```

for displaying the IP Address you can use:

```
NSLog(@"ip v4: %@",[NSString getIpLocally:@"ios_cellular" ipVersion:4]);
```